# How to use delete within a GridView in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

I need a way to grab the values of columns of the row whose "Delete" button was hit in a data-bound GridView. The values in the data-bound GridView are those from a linked table, and upon hitting "Delete" on one of the rows, I would like to delete the entry from the database.

This is my gridview

```
<asp:GridView 
    ID="GridView1" 
    runat="server" 
    AllowPaging="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    DataKeyNames="Session[userId'],courseId"  //< ? for 'userId'
    style="z-index: 1; left: 222px; top: 139px; position: absolute; height: 299px; width: 458px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="department" HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="department" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="courseCode" HeaderText="Course" SortExpression="courseCode" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="courseName" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="courseName" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is my current, work in progress of my SQLDataSource. I will need the above "courseCode" and "courseName" values to select (from a different) table an unique "courseId" which I use with a session variable Session["userId"] to delete the entry from my table, thus updating my GridView.

It's important to say here that my select statement is only taking in one variable (it is using Session["userId"]), while my delete statement doesn't only use Session["userId"], it also uses two other variables.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
        ID="SqlDataSource1" 
        runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="GetPreviouslyTakenCourses" 
        SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM UserHasCourse WHERE UserHasCourse.userId=@userId AND (SELECT Id FROM Courses WHERE courseCode=@courseCode AND courseName=@courseName)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="1" Name="userId" SessionField="userId" Size="10" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="userId" SessionField="userId" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="courseCode" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="courseName" />
        </DeleteParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I know I am missing a few things, if there is any additional information needed I can update my question.

**Update 1:** Need to move DataKeyNames into the GridView. An additional question is now how to pass a Session variable into DataKeyNames

**Update 2:** ControlID was removed. ControlParameter changed to Parameter within SQLDataSource (Is this correct?)

**Update 3:** Am I able to grab the userId value (which is equal to Session["userId"]) within my select query, and make it hidden, thus able to use it in my delete statement?